# High availability configuration of CAS

Tags: java, redis, tomcat8, haproxy, cas

I'm implementing CAS 5 as High Availability on Java 8 and Tomcat 8 with haproxy as load balancer and redis as ticket registry. For ticket registry followed details given [here](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Redis-Ticket-Registry.html). Coming to deployment CAS deployed on two tomcats say T1 and T2.

```
                    haproxy (80)
                        /\
                       /  \
                      /    \
            tomcat (T1)    tomcat (T2)
                      \    /
                       \  /
                        \/
                   redis (6379)

          T1 and T2, where CAS was deployed
```

**haproxy conf:**

```
cookie JSESSIONID prefix nocache
server tomcat1 127.0.0.1:1111 cookie t1 check inter 1000
server tomcat2 127.0.0.1:2222 cookie t2 check inter 1000
```

When I hit the URL, it's connected to T1. I'm able to login and ticket created (authenticated on T1 and ticket validated on T2). After login if I shutdown T1 and logout it gets connecting to T2 and giving below error

> DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.web.support.CookieRetrievingCookieGenerator:
> 141] -  java.lang.NullPointerException: null
> at org.apereo.cas.web.support.EncryptedCookieValueManager.obtainCookieValue(EncryptedCookieValueManager.java:35)
> ~[cas-server-core-cookie-api-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.apereo.cas.web.support.CookieRetrievingCookieGenerator.retrieveCookieValue(CookieRetrievingCookieGenerator.java:139)
> ~[cas-server-core-cookie-api-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216)
> ~[spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:470)
> ~[spring-cloud-context-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
> ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)
> ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at org.apereo.cas.web.support.CookieRetrievingCookieGenerator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$230a627a.retrieveCookieValue()
> ~[cas-server-core-cookie-api-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.apereo.cas.web.flow.logout.TerminateSessionAction.terminate(TerminateSessionAction.java:72)
> ~[cas-server-support-actions-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.apereo.cas.web.flow.logout.TerminateSessionAction.doExecute(TerminateSessionAction.java:54)
> ~[cas-server-support-actions-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
> ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216)
> ~[spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:470)
> ~[spring-cloud-context-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
> ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
> ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy169.execute(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
> at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
> ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:77)
> ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
> ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
> ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:101)
> ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
> ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:527)
> ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:368)
> ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:223)
> ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:139)
> ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216)
> ~[spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:470)
> ~[spring-cloud-context-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
> ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
> ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy167.launchExecution(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
> at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:264)
> ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
> ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
> ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
> ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
> ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
> ~[servlet-api.jar:?]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
> ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
> ~[servlet-api.jar:?]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apereo.cas.web.nic.filter.SarathiXSSFilter.doFilter(SarathiXSSFilter.java:83)
> ~[classes/:5.3.2]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apereo.cas.web.nic.filter.CASFilter.doFilter(CASFilter.java:94)
> ~[classes/:5.3.2]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apereo.cas.web.support.AuthenticationCredentialsThreadLocalBinderClearingFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationCredentialsThreadLocalBinderClearingFilter.java:30)
> ~[cas-server-core-web-api-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apereo.cas.security.RequestParameterPolicyEnforcementFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterPolicyEnforcementFilter.java:261)
> ~[cas-server-security-filter-2.0.10.2.jar:2.0.10.2]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apereo.cas.security.ResponseHeadersEnforcementFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeadersEnforcementFilter.java:237)
> ~[cas-server-security-filter-2.0.10.2.jar:2.0.10.2]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apereo.cas.security.AddResponseHeadersFilter.doFilter(AddResponseHeadersFilter.java:94)
> ~[cas-server-security-filter-2.0.10.2.jar:2.0.10.2]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111)
> ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
> ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
> ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
> ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apereo.cas.logging.web.ThreadContextMDCServletFilter.doFilter(ThreadContextMDCServletFilter.java:91)
> ~[cas-server-core-logging-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
> ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
> ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130)
> ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
> ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105)
> ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123)
> ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apereo.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:66)
> ~[inspektr-common-1.8.3.GA.jar:1.8.3.GA]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
> ~[log4j-web-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
> ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
> ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
> ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2500)
> ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.32]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2489)
> ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.32]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_251]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> ~[tomcat-util.jar:8.0.32]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_251]>
> DEBUG [org.apereo.cas.web.flow.logout.TerminateSessionAction: 79] -
>  DEBUG
> [org.apereo.cas.web.support.TGCCookieRetrievingCookieGenerator: 217] -
> <Removed cookie with name [TGC]> DEBUG
> [org.apereo.cas.web.WarningCookieRetrievingCookieGenerator: 217] -
> <Removed cookie with name [CASPRIVACY]> DEBUG
> [org.apereo.cas.web.flow.logout.TerminateSessionAction: 102] - Destroying application session DEBUG
> [org.apereo.cas.web.flow.logout.TerminateSessionAction: 84] - Terminated all CAS sessions successfully.

If I didn't shutdown the logged in instance then there is no issue, able to logout and ticket was destroyed successfully.

I've tried two ways.

1. With tomcat session replication. Added `<distributable/>` to CAS and uncommented `SimpleTcpCluster` in `server.xml`.
2. Without session replication.

But issue is same (if I down logged in instance giving above error).

**EncryptedCookieValueManager:**

```
public String obtainCookieValue(final String cookie, final HttpServletRequest request) {
    final String cookieValue = cipherExecutor.decode(cookie, new Object[]{}).toString();
    ............
```

Am I missing anything here? Any one please help in this.

Answer (score 0):

After fighting some days, I found issue that `decode` returns `null`. Upon that invoking `toString()`, gets error. Actually I forgot to configure below

```
cas.tgc.crypto.encryption.key=
cas.tgc.crypto.signing.key=
cas.webflow.crypto.signing.key=
cas.webflow.crypto.encryption.key=
```

CAS generates above by default. So both CAS applications generated keys are different. So that `decode` returns `null`.